# References do not appear in the PDF file of my book in Latex

Tags: reference, latex

I had compiled my work without any error in Latex a few months ago on a PC. However, it does work correctly on my new PC. My book.tex file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}

\usepackage[sort, numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}

%some packages are added

\begin{document}

\author{XYZ}
\title{abc}
\maketitle

\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\end{document}
```

My chapter1.tex and chapter2.tex look like the followings:

```
\chapter{Chapter one}
\cite[ref1]
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{refCH1}
```

and

```
\chapter{Chapter two}
\cite[ref2]
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{refCH2}
```

The refCH1.bib and refCH2.bib look like as:

```
@article{ref1,
  title={ABC1},
  author={AAA}
}
```

and

```
@article{ref2,
  title={ABC2},
  author={BBB}
}
```

The result of production pdf file, book.pdf, does not contain the references at the end of each chapter. Moreover, [?]’s appear instead of correct citations (e.g., [1], [2], …). The following messages appear in the console:

```
Command Line:   makeindex.exe "book.idx"
Startup Folder: C:\...\SpringerBook\Springer_book_latex\templates

This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file book.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in book.ind.
Transcript written in book.ilg.


Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "book.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\...\SpringerBook\Springer_book_latex\templates

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(book.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 68 languages loaded.
(svmono.cls
Document Class: svmono 2009/12/17 v5.5 
Springer Verlag global LaTeX document class for monographs
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class

LaTeX Warning: Citation `ref1' in file `chapter1' on page 1 undefined on input line 20.

LaTeX Warning: Citation `ref2' in file `chapter2' on page 1 undefined on input line 20.

No file chapter1.bbl.


Command Line:   bibtex.exe "book"
Startup Folder: C:\...\SpringerBook\Springer_book_latex\templates

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: book.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: chapter1.aux
A level-1 auxiliary file: chapter2.aux
Illegal, another \bibstyle command---line 74 of file chapter1.aux
 : \bibstyle
 :          {spbasic}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Illegal, another \bibdata command---line 75 of file chapter2.aux
 : \bibdata
 :         {refCH1}
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
Database file #1: refCH1.bib
(There were # error messages)
```

Comment: The syntax `\cite[ref2]` is wrong, it should be `\cite{ref2}`

Comment: Also you should not run bibtex on the whole file, but on each included file sepereatly